# best place to put variables (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net

(LANGUAGE : VB.NET)

(TYPE : DESKTOP)

(GOAL : STATISTICS on dashboard)

1- What is the best place to place "New datatable" without making mistakes? Is it before (For..Next) or After

2- I spin a large number of tables in the database every 10 seconds Is there any advice for a clean code Because the program gets heavy after hours

thank you

```
 Dim dtt As New DataTable
    Dim daa As New OleDbDataAdapter

    For i = 0 To 50

        'Dim dtt As New DataTable
        'Dim daa As New OleDbDataAdapter

        dtt.Clear()
        daa = New OleDbDataAdapter("select count(ID)      from TABLE_" & i & "          ", cn)
        daa.Fill(dtt)

    Next
```

Comment: You should do an internet search like: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=.net+variable+scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you create your `daa` and `dtt` variables *inside* the `For`-loop, they will be "destroyed" at the end of every loop execution and re-created in a next loop execution. That has to do with [scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/declared-elements/how-to-control-the-scope-of-a-variable). If you actually want that to happen depends on how you intend to process the data on your dashboard. You only show code that retrieves data from the database, so based on the code you provided it cannot be determined what the "correct" way would be in your scenario.

You should also mind that several objects can (and should) be [disposed](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects) if you are done using them. If you fail to properly dispose such objects (like your `DataTable` and `OleDbDataAdapter` instances), they will stay "alive" somewhere in your computer's memory (probably until the application is terminated). Apart from eating memory, they might hold other system resources occupied as well. That can be one of the main reasons why your program becomes "heavier" in the course of time while it is running.

Finally, I would suggest to combine all those separate SQL queries in a single SQL query. Then you can execute that single query every 10 seconds. Every query you execute has some overhead, so combining them as much as possible will almost always be somewhat faster.

There are at least two possible strategies for creating a single query for your scenario. One querying strategy uses multiple subqueries:

```
SELECT
  (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TABLE_1) AS COUNT_TABLE_1,
  (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TABLE_2) AS COUNT_TABLE_2,
  ...
```

Another querying strategy uses UNIONs:

```sql
SELECT 'TABLE_1' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(ID) AS ROW_COUNT FROM TABLE_1
UNION
SELECT 'TABLE_2' AS TABLE_NAME, COUNT(ID) AS ROW_COUNT FROM TABLE_2
UNION
...
```

Comment: "Bart Hofland"
thank you very much for your help and support
UNIONs best solution